# R named vectors in one statement

Tags: r, vector

Is there a way to accomplish this in one line?

```
my_var <- c("Mary", "Jane")
names(my_var) <- c("first", "last")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
my_var <- c("first" = "Mary", "last" = "Jane")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `setNames`

```
my_var <- setNames(c("Mary", "Jane"), c("first", "last"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `structure`:

```
my_var <- structure(c("Mary", "Jane"), names = c("first", "last"))
```

You can set other attributes with that too like `dim`, `class`, etc.