# Is this `c` function from Python?

Tags: python, data-science

I have some code which I think is Python doing this:

```py
chevy = c("Mileage"=30000, "Cylinder"=4, "Doors"=2, "Cruise"=1, "Sound"=1, "Leather"=1)
```

It's a code example I'm supposed to work with but doesn't have imports. We've been using Pandas, SciPy, NumPy, Matplotlib, etc. I remember seeing this somewhere but can't find how to import it, perhaps some sort of way of creating associative arrays.

Is this line of code valid?

Comment: There is a c() function in R, but it does not look like there is an equivalent with the same name in python. Are we sure the code works?

Comment: @Vib I am not an R expert, but don't you define vectors with `c`?

Comment: @kabanus Not an expert either but a quick google search suggests its used to combine its arguments into a vector

Comment: @Vib indeed. I am wondering if there is a vector with "named" positions, such as a `namedtuple` in Python. That would also make sense.

Comment: @Vib See edit to my answer. I am putting my money on a named vector now.

Comment: Yeah, this is absolutely not Python. You can't quote keyword argument names in Python.

Comment: @user2357112 doi, thanks for the hammer on my head. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially thought this can be anything that accepts keyword arguments, but of course this is wrong - [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) correctly states you cannot quote keyword arguments in Python. **Hence this is invalid Python syntax.**

**This does look like** R syntax for named vectors - here is one question on how to instantiate them as a one liner: [R named vectors in one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629150/r-named-vectors-in-one-statement).

Comment: Damn, they gave us R. It was in a Jupyter notebook where everything else is Python! Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

kabanus is correct that this is a valid line of R code. If you are looking for the *equivalent* in Python, I would use a pandas Series object. Series objects are 1-dimensional arrays where you can perform vector mathematics operations just like in R. What makes Series objects different from numpy arrays is they can also carry a named index like a named vector in R. The code to instantiate this object looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
chevy = pd.Series([30_000, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], index=["Mileage", "Cylinder", "Doors", "Cruise", "Sound", "Leather"])
print(chevy["Mileage"])
```